# Cotton-pencil-diamond tribond

Tags: tribond

Three things:

> Cotton
>
> Pencil
>
> Diamond

What do they all have in common?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the answer to the question is

> Carbon.

Cotton:

> Cotton is a biological substance,  and thus carbon based.

Pencil:

> The pencil lead is made of graphite, which is carbon.

Diamond:

> A diamond is just another form of carbon.

Comment: If this turns out to be the intended answer, it's too broad. Millions of different sorts of things have carbon atoms in their molecules.

Comment: @RosieF, no matter what the answer and what the three things in a tribond are, they would all be too broad by this definition. After all, perhaps pretty much everything could be related to a lot more than 3 things. The question would have been too broad if it had many possible correct answers, not if many more questions could fit the answer(s).

Comment: @MariaDeleva I think Rosie's point of contention is that two of them _are_  or contain something that _is_ carbon while the third merely contains a compound with molecules that have carbon atoms.

Answer (score 9):

What do they all have in common?

> Tips.

Cotton:

> [image: Cotton tips]

([Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=cotton%20tip&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS696US697&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi369qCoM_OAhUD5yYKHSNCBDkQ_AUIBygC))

Pencil:

> [image: Pencil tips]

([Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=cotton%20tip&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS696US697&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi369qCoM_OAhUD5yYKHSNCBDkQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=pencil%20tip))

Diamond:

> [image: Diamond tips]

([Source](https://www.google.com/search?q=cotton%20tip&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS696US697&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=979&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi369qCoM_OAhUD5yYKHSNCBDkQ_AUIBygC#tbm=isch&q=diamond%20tip))

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! To be honest, I think this answer is better than the accepted one.

Comment: I would agree with accepted.

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility in addition to the other two answers

> Their hardness (or softness) is desired or otherwise significant

cotton

> Many people want cotton to be as soft as possible, even using thread count as a rough measure of softness of cotton sheets

pencil

> Artists, drafters, and other people use pencils of varying hardness

diamond

> diamond defines 10, the highest hardness, on the Mohs scale

Comment: Clever way to think about the problem, +1. Almost think this is better than the carbon answer, since cotton just doesn't fit as well as it should

Comment: @AvikMohan, I agree - it is much better answer than the one I was seeking. Still, I am not sure if it would be fair to accept it - as I wasn't as clever to think of it myself.

Answer (score 6):

They are all things which can be made into

> dresses.

Cotton:

> [image]

Pencil:

> [image]

and Diamond:

> [image]

Comment: Well so can [meat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lady_Gaga%27s_meat_dress) or just about anything else...

Comment: Well, that was an unexpected answer...  +1 for the original answer.

Answer (score 5):

They all involve:

> Carbon

Cotton

> Cellulose fibers (Plant made from carbon)

Pencil

> Graphite in the lead (Carbon is soft graphite)

Diamond

> Diamonds are compressed carbon

---

Or

> They are all ways to describe clothing
> (Do a google search on "Cotton Pencil Diamond" & you'll see what I mean)
>   
>  **Cotton** Blend **Diamond** Print **Pencil** Skirt